# Speak ill of or speak ill on me

Tags: prepositions

Good day, my question is which preposition is correct? (OF/ON)

> I hate co-workers who speak ill **of** me.

Or

> I hate co-workers who speak ill **on** me.

P.s: I already googled it just now, and there is no precise answer to this particular question I am asking. Tnx and pls. Help.

Comment: How did you "google" it? I just searched for [define "to speak ill of"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=AS5iWuroCcedkgX8xamAAw&q=define+%22to+speak+ill+of%22&oq=define+%22to+speak+ill+of%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1.2879.11199.0.11940.15.14.0.0.0.0.296.1493.5j4j2.12.0.crnk_dmh...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.12.1595.6..0j35i39k1j0i7i30k1j0i131k1j0i3k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i7i5i30k1.104.ePRq9j_m-3E) and got "About 138,000 results", the first half-dozen of which were all dictionary definitions. Searching for *define "to speak ill **on**"* got "About 3,850 results" (all junk, no dictionaries).

Comment: Hello there, I typed 'speak ill on me' (coz I think speak ill on me is more appropriate/sensible preposition to use) then, 'speak ill of...' appears in almost every entry. These entries do not answer my question: speak ill on me(specifically) or speak ill on me.

Comment: @JohnArvin  Are you saying English prepositions frequently don't make sense?  What a shocker!  :D

Comment: The idiom is: to speak ill of someone. No doubt about it. One can't google these things really. There is all sorts of junk recorded by google.

Comment: @Lambie: I dispute that (which is why I've voted to close for lack of even *basic* research). Googling ["speak ill **on** me"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22speak+ill+on+me%22&oq=%22speak+ill+on+me%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.2815j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets just **3** hits (*and* a Google-generated message saying *Did you mean: "speak ill **of** me"*). Clicking on their suggested alternative gets "About 168,000 results", which should make the situation blindingly obvious.

Comment: @Lambie: I think that FumbleFingers's point is that one can draw inference from the vast discrepancy in the size of google results. I.e. "speak ill of" is over 40 times more popular, therefore it is more likely to be correct. Additionally, since "speak ill on me" returns results for "speak ill of me", per your comment, "speak ill of me" seems more likely.

Comment: @sharur - That's well-said, but there is more to it than raw numbers. Sometimes fewer hits means an expression is incorrect, or unidiomatic; other times, it's perfectly fine, but it may have a different meaning and simply be used less frequently. Looking at numbers is a good place to start, but perusing the results can help, too. Are the hits from news articles and published works? Or blog posts written by people who seem to have poor English skills?

Comment: @sharur- regarding googling, I agree with J.R, numbers of searched items do not necessarily mean accuracy. Also, if you typed in 'speak ill on me' it will turn into DID YOU MEAN: speak ill of me result(which I agree with you, moreover, the likelyness(as what you have said due to quantity exhibited) of being accurate of these 'entries' is what I doubt about coz it turns into the other way(instead of directly 'speak ill on me result) As a result, I prefer to ask this issue on this site as exceptionally reliable.

Comment: @Andrew: I have just flagged you for being impolite. Enjoy.

Comment: @JohnArvin  if you're going to learn English, you might well try to learn to recognize satire when you see it, and also how the use of emojis can affect the *tone* of a comment.  My comment wasn't meant to be rude or mean-spirited, but rather a jest at how English is **well-known** for irregularities, idioms, exceptions, quirks, and completely random "rules' that English learners have to deal with.  It's kind of a nightmare, which is why I'm happy to help out where I can. The flag itself is no big deal, but next time please consider whether the comment is laughing *with* you and not *at* you.

Comment: Look here is a great example. At the dawn of the internet (circa 1994), colleagues of mine in Brazil, insisted on a word usage that simply did not exist in English. They kept posting it over and over on the Internet. It is still there and the word still does not exist in English but it has a google existence of its own. So, unless a person knows it does not exist, others who are uninformed will be lead to think it exists "in the English language".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please read my prior post. I said speak ill of me. Why are you asking me if that is what I meant??

Comment: @Lambie: That wasn't what ***I*** meant! :) I was disagreeing with your *One can't google these things really* - which should be contextually obvious, since I then showed how easy it was for me to compare google results for the two different possibilities OP couldn't decide between.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Google cannot determine usage. So, one can't google these things really. You can literally google them but it will not tell you anything much. There are time when 2 hits are right and 100 are wrong.

Comment: @Lambie: I'd question whether it *ever* makes sense to claim that a usage with 2 hits in Google Books is "right", and that the one with 100 hits is "wrong". But in this specific case the ratio isn't just 50:1 - it's well over fifty ***thousand*** to one. In the long run, "correct" usage is whatever the vast majority actually adopt, not what some (perhaps outdated or misguided) grammatical rule says.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just exaggerated it. There are times when usage is either this or that usage. Both being fine. Google cannot tell that either. Google, in short, is a recording instrument, not an editor.  It has no discernment.

Comment: @Lambie: There are certainly contexts such as [***ripe/rife** with opportunity*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rife+with+opportunity%2Cripe+with+opportunity&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crife%20with%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cripe%20with%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0) where NGrams/Google Books can't tell you which is "right". But when you get results like that, the only sensible interpretation is that ***both*** are valid. And personally I don't really accept the concept of "correct" when talking about markedly minority usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers speak ill on is never right in regular writing. It might be some highly dialectal usage. But generally, that is not what one imparts to ELLers, in questions such as the one asked here re co-workers.

Comment: I am conflicted on whether to close this because a dictionary may not have an entry for a usage that does not exist. On the other hand, a simple google request will give you a "did you mean" message, which is a pretty clear signal that it is not a recognized usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Of" is the correct preposition in this case, due to idiomatic usage of the phrase "speaking ill".

"Speaking of" someone or something means to mention them. "Speaking ill of" someone means to mention something bad about them. "Speaking on" X means that X is either a topic of conversation or that X is a platform on which one speaks (e.g. Skype, speakerphone, a stage, etc.).

Alternatively, if I were to make negative things about a person the topic of a speech or conversation, I could say "speaking on the topic of [insert negative things here]", or simply use "speaking ill" as a short hand.

Source: I am a native NA English speaker.